# How to copy class and function name in Blackfire report

Tags: blackfire

When I am copy-pasting method name from Blackfire profile, I am getting a reversed string like this:
`sgnitsiLredivorPdaol::yrotisopeRresopmoC\yrotisopeR\resopmoC`

What is intended way to copy a proper method name (not reversed)?
Why does Blackfire has such behaviour? Is this some kind of stupid joke or copy-paste protection?

[image: Blackfire profile page with DOM inspector]

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a UX issue we currently have in Blackfire, let me explain it to you:

- We want to display the end of the namespace/classname value in this part of the interface
- We want to have a text-overflow ellipsis on the left part of the value.

Unfortunately, using `text-overflow: ellipsis` on the left of the text is not supported by modern browsers at the moment.

There are two ways to do that: Either know the width of the text, work with a fixed width column and truncate programmatically or use a hack, revert the letters, change the text direction from left-to-right to right-to-left locally and use traditional text-overflow.

As we deal with a resizable UI here, we chose the second option, and this is the one that provide the better experience at the moment. However, as you notice, this issue remains.

We're thinking about a fix for this issue. It might be with the Clipboard API.

In the meantime, here's the way you can copy/paste the value :
Just expand a node and copy from the inner box, see:

[image]

Hope it helps you until we find a better solution.